# Does google ads id matter for google play store install count?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api, google-advertising-id

We have created AppTracking SDK for Android App analytics , we track app installs.
In fact issue is app install count in google play store and our SDK install count is different .I used google ads id in SDK with ensuring it's polices. What is issue i'm unable to find.Does google ads id matter for google play store install count ?

Answer (score 0):

google ad will give unique key for 1 App for publishing...and you can use the same key in another app for displaying google ads.so if you are using same key for 2 diff apps so the count for google sdk will be double. so u cant compare those two...